# Multiple Filters at the Excel Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

[image]

well this is my source table in excel if I add a pivot for this source it looks like this

[image]

and I want make a multible-filter at this. for example how can I calculate which citys is that less than 4 days stays  and more than 2000 $ spend for trip at there.

[image]

I mean it will show just this.

Comment: @pnuts because it's not MORE than 2000, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure there is a spare row above the PT, select columns that contain PT and filter to select is less than 4 for TRIP Sum of Day and Greater than $2000 for TRIP Sum of Money:

[image: Filter example]

Comment: Select what? Filter how? Screenshot?

Comment: well it's not cool, because it makes ugly result, it is hidding titles (Sum of Day, Sum of Money and etc.)